# Lamp plugged into outlet controlled by 3 way switch suddenly dim when switch is off

Tags: electrical, switch

So, I've done nothing to cause this, just getting that out of the way.

Yesterday I noticed that my lamp was dim. I figured it was some problem with the lamp or bulb, but I realized the 3 way switch was in the OFF position. I turned it on, and the lamp went to normal.

This switch controls the top of several outlets in my room.

I got a volt meter and the top of the outlet reads ~20V with the switch in the off position, ~122V in the on position.

I really don't know the first thing about this stuff and am going to have an electrician come and check it out, but any ideas what could be causing this?

FWIW I don't know the voltage measurements before, but the lamp always turned fully off as of two days ago.

Comment: 3-way switch means you have *two separate switches*, normally on opposite sides of the room. What happens if the "problem" switch is left *on* and you turn off the lamp with the other switch?

Comment: Could be a carbon track burned into one of the switches (perhaps by lightning strike nearby, or "teasing" the switch by slow closure). As @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact states, try flipping each switch the other way. If that completely shuts the lamp, then one switch needs to be replaced. Also check if one switch feels warm while the lamp is on, but dimmed -- that's the broken one.

Comment: These are standard 3 way switches right? No dimming control on either (that would be a code violation) I have seen it is the reason I ask.

Comment: Neither switch turns the lamp off fully. Both used to. No dimming involved anywhere.